# Connection String to use Microsoft Text Driver with a preconfigured data source name

Tags: odbc, oledb, jet, text-driver

We are currently using the following connection string in a script to read a CSV via the Microsoft Text Driver:

```
myConn.ConnectionString= "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=O:\;Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
```

Instead of specifying the details to connect to the CSV in the code like we have done above, we want to use a **data source name** in the code.

I.e. a data source that would be configured on the 'System DSN' section of the ODBC snap on the workstation that the script is run in. This ODBC would have the required details linking it to the CSV.

*For example: All users will have a Microsoft Text Driver ODBC with the name `ODBC1` setup on their system, and we need to be able to refer to this data source name without putting in the actual details to connect to the CSV in the code.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! All I needed to use a data source name in the code was to replace the code in the question with:

```
myConn.ConnectionString= "DSN=ODBC1;"
```